# Double entry accounting database design/schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database, accounting

I am currently learning how to design accounting databases for payment systems like PayPal or PayTim etc. In one of my project I just can't figure how and where to apply double-entry patterns as I learned it is very important in accounting.

So my project is intended to work like PayPal for learning purposes. I created some tables such as:

1. **payments_table** - Which store every payment the user pays for service or sending to somebody (Stores money that circulates within the system).
2. **transfers_in_table** - Stores every transaction from Visa/MasterCard *(Records money that is coming in the system)*
3. **withdrawals_table** - This stores every money that user withdrawals. (Stores money which going out of the system)
4. **transfers_out_table** - Stores money that has been successfully withdrawn by the user.

So when the user1 pays somebody or for service(lets say user2) the flow will be like

**User1**->Visa->My Project -> **User2**->**Some Fees**->Bank.

How do I implement double entry for the situation like this, not to forget I need to store withdrawing **fees** in database too so that every calculation will balance?
I was thinking of having another table ledger but I dont think if is good solution.

Tables summary

```
payments_table - id,amount, and userId(FK)
transfers_in_table - id,amount and paymentId(FK)
withdrawals_table - id,amount and userId(FK)
transfers_out_table - id,amount and withdrawalId(FK)
```

Comment: Generally modern accounting/ financials systems tend to work with a single (unified/ consolidated/ general) ledger, where a single table is used to store all financial transactions, and the type is one of the attributes stored in that table.  It makes reporting MUCH easier, possibly at the cost of some redundancy.  It also allows for double-entry to be much easier to implement.  If you want extra data, e.g. a payment might have a load of information that you don't want to clutter your general ledger with, then you could create an extra table and hang it off the ledger table.

Comment: More specifically, in your case you have two transactions, which could be seen as being as simple as User 1 credits ledger, User 2 debits ledger (and probably some link between the two, to show they are related).  But you could also make this much more complex, by introducing a reconciliation account or two into the mix.  Adding reconciliation (sometimes called "control" accounts) also gives you the ability to add up all the payments coming in and out of the system without having to go directly to the ledger table.

Comment: @RichardHansell thanks for response, I will focus on merging both tables into one! By the way **by introducing a reconciliation account or two into the mix** do you have any link where I can study this?

Comment: Google is your friend.  Here's an article that discusses the use of control accounts, "accounts receivable" is the usual example: https://www.double-entry-bookkeeping.com/bookkeeping-basics/control-accounts/